# convert string to date in Python

Tags: python

Python newbie here, so this is probably an easy question. I'm trying to extract part of a string and convert it to date format (there's no time involved). I'm trying to copy approaches I've seen online, but I get the message

> ValueError: time data '2017-07-10' does not match format '%y-%m-%d'.

I'm probably using the wrong format somewhere, and I'm not sure how to proceed. Thanks very much for any suggestions you may have.

```
#convert the audit_date to a list so it can be
# sliced
audit_date_list = list(audit_date)
# Slice audit_date_list to get chars at indexes
# 13-22
# only, then join those chars
audit_date_slice = "".join(audit_date_list[13:23])
#convert audit_date_slice to date format
audit_date_final = datetime.datetime.strptime(audit_date_slice, '%y-%m-%d').date()
print(audit_date_final)
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please [mark it as 'accepted’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use capital Y for four-digits year:

```
audit_date_final = datetime.datetime.strptime(audit_date_slice, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to remember the format, try using `dateutil`, it recognizes most of the formats and it's shipped with Anaconda.

```
from dateutil import parser

audit_date_final = parser.parse(audit_date_slice)
```